# PHP replace "|" symbol to html list <li>

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this value form database

**10:00|10:15|10:30**

and I need to replace this symbol `|` to html list `<li>`

Like this:

```
<li><input class="left" type="text" value="10:00" /><div class="del right ">x</div></li>
<li><input class="left" type="text" value="10:15" /><div class="del right ">x</div></li>
<li><input class="left" type="text" value="10:30" /><div class="del right ">x</div></li>
```

Comment: Show what you tried. What exactly doesnt work. Here's a hint to get you started. use `explode` and then loop over it

Comment: Use $items = explode('|', $str), then use each item via $items[index]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `explode()`, and then build the list from the resulting array:

```
$str = "10:00|10:15|10:30";
$out = "";

foreach ( explode( "|", $str ) as $value ) {
  $out .= "<li>{$value}</li>";
}

echo "<ul>{$out}</ul>";
```

Which results in:

```
<ul>
    <li>10:00</li>
    <li>10:15</li>
    <li>10:30</li>
</ul>
```

Adding your inputs is a breeze from here:

```
foreach ( explode( "|", $str ) as $value ) {
    $out .= "<li>
                 <input class='left' type='text' value='{$value}' />
                 <div class='del right'>x</div>
             </li>";
}
```

Leaving you with the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input class='left' type='text' value='10:00' />
        <div class='del right'>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class='left' type='text' value='10:15' />
        <div class='del right'>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class='left' type='text' value='10:30' />
        <div class='del right'>x</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each result using the | as a deliminator.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it into an array using

```
$input = '10:00|10:15|10:30';
$list = explode('|', $input);
```

Than iterate over the array with a foreach

```
foreach ($list as $li) {
    echo '<li />' . $li;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<?php
    $result = explode('|','10:00|10:15|10:30');
    foreach($result as $single)
    {
        echo '<li><input class="left" type="text" value="'.$single.'" /><div class="del right ">x</div></li>'."\r\n";
    }
?>
```